# How to calculate capacity of a memory by given a range of address?

Tags: ram, memory-address

I have another exercice that I couldn't resolve,

A central memory composed by two memory module(RAM).the total address range attributed to the central memory is:
FROM 0000 0000H TO 3FFF FFFFH

1/Give the total capacity of the central memory (Megabyte and Gegabyte)

2/Give the capacity of each memory module(RAM)

3/Give the first and last address of each memory module(RAM)

Sorry for the bad translation the exercice is an french.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 1 is easy. The range from 0000 0000H to 3FFF FFFFH contains 4000 0000H addresses. (Just like 0 to 3 is four addresses, 0, 1, 2, and 3.) 4000 0000H is 1,073,741,824 decimal, or 1GB. 1,024 MB.

2 is no problem. If two memory modules give 1GB, then each module must be 512MB.

3 is impossible. We don't know if the memory modules are consecutive or interleaved. But if we assume they're consecutive, which I imagine is what the exercise wants us to do, then the first one must be 0000 0000H to 1FFF FFFFH and the second one must be 2000 0000H to 3FFF FFFFH.

Note that mapping memory modules consecutively is generally considered dumb. It means that in the typical case where the memory module bandwidth is the limiting factor, if an application is only using the first half of memory, it's only using one of the two modules, wasting half the available memory bandwidth. (Though, in the less common case where the memory is as fast or faster than the CPU or its memory bus, it doesn't matter.)